# When to use React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I've been learning part of the MEAN/MERN stack and feel somewhat comfortable using MongoDB, Express, and Node. I'm moving onto the A/R of the stacks and am having a bit of trouble understanding when these are applicable and when they're not.

To try to put my thoughts into words, I would ask this:

Is Angular and React applicable to nearly all web applications or were they built for a certain niche? For instance, one of my first projects will be creating a portal for employees to use for various tools to help them with their work as well as to transition from Excel based forms to web based forms.

When creating a site like this, is Mongo/Express/Node enough?

I'm kind of struggling to explain this as this React course I've been trying to complete is making my brain feel like its over flowing. I've learned HTML/CSS/JS + Mongo/Express/Node over the past few months including ES2015-2017 and such so immediately learning React on top of that feels a bit overwhelming. For some reason my head is having trouble 'Thinking in React'. Not necessarily breaking things down to components, but the props and states aspect of it all.

For instance, I understand what pure functions are but I don't feel experienced enough to know how to refactor a non-pure function to a pure one and be confident.

I hope this is making sense... Coding has been wonderful. Not only am I having fun but it's really given me motivation to better myself and my knowledge and as well as given me a goal to reach.

Any direction on how to tackle React as a newbie would be extremely helpful.

Comment: React and Angular handle your view layer. If you're only hoping to expose a RESTful API then you're good to go with Mongo, Express, and Node. If your application needs any kind of user interface (generally the case with most web apps) then you can explore React and Angular.

To start off, you should just worry about which seems to make more sense to you, realistically they can both get anything done.

Comment: The above comment states it well. I will just add that this Udemy React tutorial is really good - https://www.udemy.com/react-2nd-edition/learn/v4/overview

Comment: I'm actually using a Udemy course by Colt Steele as well. (Advanced Web Developer Bootcamp) I took his beginner course and it worked well but the inclusion of the new instructors and their different teaching styles made things a bit harder for me. I'll definitely check these out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd like to share my thoughts on how you can get started with React. Maybe a first look at https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links would be nice, if you already familiar basic react and its enviroment. Here the section **Data Flow: “State” and “Props”** seems to be something you seek for.
Don´t get overwhelmed by all the surrounding libraries, concepts and so on. It actually will get pretty clear after you built your first own react and later redux applications. The don´t have to look nice, just tackle concepts like Higher Order Components, passing data from childs to parents etc.

If you´ve got questions feel free to ask. Im digging in react too.

Answer (score -4):

This is a very wide question, so I will give you a narrow answer: REACT

Seriously, just stop searching for these type of answers because there is no right answer. Angular programmers will tell you angular and vice versa.

Just GO and start coding man :)

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. I'm aware that asking which to use is a silly question as it's completely subjective. What I mean is, when is it a good time to use something like Angular/React. I'm struggling to learn one of them at the moment so I wanted to clarify if it was event relevant to my current project.

Comment: I know, I had these doubts myself recently. We can't give you any specific answer since you described your app in one sentence. Also you can only get a personal opinion. For real answer you have to contact someone who is master of both and describe him in details what you want to build. Good luck.